# Change Color of Tagged Favorite Questions

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I feel as if my eyes are drawn naturally **away** from what should be an attention grabbing  color of the questions marked with one of my "interested" tags. The tepid brown of `#ffefc6` doesn't quiet work for me. I feel as if the question should be brighter i.e. questions I have not marked are colored and the questions I might be interested in are white. It's gotten to the point where I've removed tags from my interested because I've noticed myself skipping over questions I would have liked to answer. I could put more tags in my "ignored" and leave my favorites blank, but I feel as if this is a corruption of the system.

What to do? I think `#FFF` for interested, `#DDD` for unmarked and `#AAA` for ignored tags. Or some similar color scheme.

Of course it'd be ***really*** cool to customize the color, but as a web designer/ developer myself I know the pains/ overhead style customization on a per user basis can cause.

You could call this senseless whining, but I think this would be a subtle change that would make Stackoverflow just that tiny bit better.

Could I write my own stylesheets or plugin to change this? Yes. Do I want to? No.

Others must have this problem as well.

Comment: I did away with the highlighting entirely - I agree, the particular color that is used is quite painful to look at.

Comment: The only questions I ever see on the homepage are those deemed interesting and thus highlighted. I sometimes forget that dingy yellow isn't the color used everywhere.